# Azure DevOps - Grant pipeline permissions to access a git repository with REST API

Tags: azure-devops

I've written a script utilizing the Azure DevOps REST API to create a project in an Azure DevOps Organization. The script also creates git repositories, build pipelines, and artifact feeds. All of these are created correctly. But, I am having one issue. When I try to run  a pipeline, I get the following message:

This pipeline needs permission to access a resource before this run can continue

A button is provided to grant this permission. BUT, I would like this just work immediately after running the script. Furthermore, the build pipeline may be triggered by an automated process with no manual involvement in the future. I can't find anything in the Azure Documentation for the REST API regarding this specifically. I've also granted all permissions to the GIT repos to the build service. But, I still get the error. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use api [Authorizedresources - Authorize Project Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/authorizedresources/authorize%20project%20resources?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to authorize the resource:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/authorizedresources?api-version=6.0-preview.1

Body:

[{"authorized":true,"id":"$queueID","name":"$queueName","type":"queue"}]
```

> There are a few things here:
>
> 1. The “Grant access permissions to all pipelines” setting is per pool per project. But this is toggled via the linked UI or set at creation
>    time in the project settings “add pool” UI.
> 2. Pools, at the Organization (or Collection) level, have two settings on them which can be seen in the “Add New Pool” dialog at the
>    Organization level. “Auto-provision this agent pool in all projects”
>    will go ahead and add the pool to all existing projects, as well as
>    when a new project is added in the future. “Grant access permission to
>    all pipelines” sets the default state of the per project level setting
>    above when adding this pool to projects.
>
> The “Default” pool comes preset with “Auto-provision” set to true, and
> “Grant access…” set to false. So when creating a new project, it will
> have the “Default” pool available, and in the “Default” pool settings
> UI for that project “Grant access…” will be set to false until a user
> updates it.
>
> To modify the “Grant access…” setting seen in the Project Settings
> Agent Pool UI linked above, you can use the API above, or go to
> Project settings -- Agent Pools, and toggled the permission as the
> screenshot below shows:
>
> [image]
>
> If you want to modify the Organization setting’s “Default” pool’s
> default value for “Grant access…” when adding the pool to new
> projects, you can do it with the following REST API:
>
> ```
> PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}
>
> Headers:
>
> Accept: /;api-version=6.0-preview.1;excludeUrls=true
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Body:
>
> {“id”:“1”,“Properties”:{“System.AutoAuthorize”: “true”}}
> ```

Refer to case: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/887182/new-pipeline-permissions-feature-causing-builds-to.html

Comment: I tried both options above and am still getting the prompt: This pipeline needs permission to access a resource before this run can continue. I checked a few other options and can't find anything in the api to grant the pipeline access to git repository.

Comment: Do you use private agent? From my test, after enable “Grant access permissions to all pipelines” setting in pool of the project, I won't get the prompt.

Comment: No, I'm using the build in Azure Pipeline pool with the built in agent

Comment: Could you share how you run a pipeline in your script? What's the result when you run Authorizedresources - Authorize Project Resources api?

Comment: Any update to this issue? Could you share how you run a pipeline in your script? What's the result when you run Authorizedresources - Authorize Project Resources api?

Comment: I have a similar issue. How do I programmatically grant access to a Service Connection?